# Ng-if string equal to null when it's in a for-loop

Tags: angular, angular-material

Been trying to get my string value, not to display when the Ng-if is false. I read that '!' on the string value should make it return false but it been just going through anyway. I think it might be because I'm not grabbing the variable from ngfor correctly but i'm not sure.

I tried label="" and it does the same thing, and also label.tostring()='' as well.

```html
 <mat-chip-list *ngFor = "let label of testValue2">
            <mat-chip ng-if="!label">{{label}}</mat-chip>
 </mat-chip-list>
```

My expected results is that it return false and not sure the mat-chip

Thanks alls

Comment: Use `*ngIf`, not `ng-if` .

Answer (score 0):

The directive for this is `*ngIf="!label"` not `ng-if="!label"`.
And `!label` is atually `false`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation of ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

You just made a mistake in syntax you should use it without `-` and with `*` in the beginning like this `*ngIf` check the example below.

```
<mat-chip-list *ngFor="let label of testValue2">
           <mat-chip *ngIf="!label">{{label}}</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

But if it's on `<ng-template></ng-template>` the syntax is a little bit different

```
<mat-chip-list *ngFor="let label of testValue2">
  <ng-template [ngIf]="!label">
    <mat-chip>{{label}}</mat-chip>
  </ng-template>
</mat-chip-list>
```

There is also an `else` for this directive.

```
<mat-chip-list *ngFor="let label of testValue2">
           <mat-chip *ngIf="!label; else secondOption">{{label}}</mat-chip>
           <ng-template #secondOption>
             <mat-chip>Second Option</mat-chip>
           </ng-template>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Again there is another syntax if `*ngIf` and `else` are on `ng-template`.

```
<mat-chip-list *ngFor="let label of testValue2">
  <ng-template [ngIf]="!label" [ngIfElse]="secondOption" ]>
    <mat-chip>{{label}}</mat-chip>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #secondOption>
    <mat-chip>Second Option</mat-chip>
  </ng-template>
</mat-chip-list>
```